# jQuery slowdown removeClass

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jQuery function that allows me to click on an image and a css class gets applied. If a different element with the same class gets clicked on, the the same class on the previous element gets removed. It works fine, except I have to click on the element twice before the `exampleimgopen` class gets applied.

I think the error is something to do with the order in the function but i am not sure what is wrong.

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
        $('.exampleimgopen').removeClass('exampleimgopen');
        $(this).toggleClass('exampleimgopen');
        $('.exampleimg').toggleClass('exampleimgclose');
    });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
    <div id="examples">
        <p>Examples:</p>
        <img src="img/1.png" class="exampleimg">
        <img src="img/2.png" class="exampleimg">
        <img src="img/3.png" class="exampleimg">
        <img src="img/4.png" class="exampleimg">
        <img src="img/5.png" class="exampleimg">
        <img src="img/6.png" class="exampleimg">
    </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#examples {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.exampleimg {
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}

.exampleimg:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.exampleimgopen {
    width:620px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.exampleimgclose {
    width:300px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: I believe that from the point of view of jQuery an element either has or does not have a certain class attached to it; jQuery itself cannot blend the rendering from the before style to the after style. However, CSS3 might offer animation features that can do what you need. What effect are you actually hoping to achieve?

Comment: can you give some idea of what you're trying to achieve this on? also maybe some css of all involved elements.

Comment: @RobertDeniro check my new answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by simplifying your code, e.g. you don't need to add `exampleimgclose` when image is closed (because your styles says it is just having a width and transition, not actually closed). After that you just need to control adding of a class to image when it is actually opened.

See this **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3o7w70ew/2/)** I made for you, and read comments I placed next to JavaScript code.

Relevant code also below:

HTML:

```
<div id="examples">
  <p>Examples:</p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/620x100" class="example-img">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/620x100" class="example-img">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/620x100" class="example-img">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#examples {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.example-img {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  transition: 0.5s width ease;
}

.example-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.example-img-open {
  width: 620px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.example-img').click(function() {
    // When clicking an image which is already open, close it
    if ($(this).hasClass("example-img-open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("example-img-open");
    }
    // When clicking an image which is not yet open, open it and close all previously opened
    else {
      $('.example-img').removeClass("example-img-open"); // Closes all others
      $(this).addClass("example-img-open");
    }
  });
});
```

You may also have noticed that I used different names for the classes. I did this only because it was hard to read the previous code, you can change them as you want.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, this was the best out of all answers as it gave all the abilities I wanted, some other answers only gave half the functionality

Comment: @RobertDeniro np. I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually fairly simple.

Inside of your CSS `.exampleimg`, use transition width. No need for any extra classes on your `img` elements.

Like so:

```
.exampleimg {
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
    transition: width 500ms; // substitute 500ms for whatever you require
}
```

Now, edit all your **HTML** `img` elements to look like this:

```
<img src="img/1.png" class="exampleimg" onClick="enlarge();"> <!-- notice onclick event !-->
```

You're **jQuery** should now go a little along the lines of:

```
function enlarge(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('exampleimgopen')){ // if clicked image isn't enlarged
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen'); // make all other image smaller
        $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen'); // make this image larger
    } else { // if image is enlarged
        $(this).removeClass('exampleimgopen'); // make the image smaller
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Now, when the user clicks on the image, it should enlarge it and make any other selected images smaller. If they click on an image already enlarged, it will be made smaller again.

Not only that, they should all ease in by 500 milliseconds.

Comment: I would suggest not to use inline "onClick" handlers. The code quickly becomes harder to read/maintain when you use this habit in larger code projects. The reason is the same than with inline CSS. There is no longer that one place where styles or javascript is defined and altering / moving elements between pages also becomes much more difficult.

Comment: @MaunoVähä I'm only using it for this example. He can edit it along the way if he would like

Comment: True, I just wanted to point out the fact because some people might browse to read this answer and at the same time start using onClick handlers "as a best practise" without knowing that it is not the case :)

Comment: @MaunoVähä fair call :)

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, although I dont want to use an onclick handler. Thanks anyway mate

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p10horrj/)

You're close - it's just that the classes are not being added / removed quite right.

Here's one way to do it that works (from the fiddle)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen exampleimgclose');
        $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen');
        $('.exampleimg').not(this).addClass('exampleimgclose');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `click` handler method, just remove the open class from all `img.exampleimg` elements. Add `close` class to all `img.exampleimg` elements, and do the exact opposite to the currently clicked element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
        $('.exampleimg').removeClass('exampleimgopen').addClass('exampleimgclose');    
        $(this).addClass('exampleimgopen').removeClass('exampleimgclose')
    });
});
```